# Tess4j : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library

Tags: eclipse, dll, tesseract, unsatisfiedlinkerror, tess4j

Im using tess4j.jar in my Eclipse project. When i run it on **eclipse** my project is **working fine**, but when i try to run the exported **runnable .jar file** it always fails due to **"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library  'libtesseract302'"** error.

I tried to fix it with solutions from similar posts but nothing worked.

1. Located the  'libtesseract302' and 'liblept168.dll' file into a "dll" folder an added it as source folder.
2. I´m running java 32bit and confirmed that the dlls are also 32bit dlls.

Error log:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libtesseract302': Can't obtain InputStream for win32-x86/libtesseract302.dll
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:271)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at brain.Main.startOCR(Main.java:292)
    at brain.Main.getOcrResult(Main.java:251)
```

Comment: "and added it as a source folder"?

Comment: I created a folder called "dll" in the project root directory. Then I clicked on that folder: Build Path -> Use as source folder. So that my libs can find the required dlls. I dont know if this is the correct way to include them into my project, but i read that this could be a solution for my problem. But in fact it didnt fix it.

Comment: So you include the DLL's in your jar file.  Unfortunately that is not enough as the operating system cannot locate native code inside jar files.  You need to have them next to the jar file in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DLLs are packaged in the JAR file, they will need to be extracted. Then set `jna.library.path` system property to the location of the DLL files (see [Tutorial](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/)).